# Can I run a JAX-RS web service on com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer?

Tags: java, jax-rs

Can I run a simple webservice like this:

```
@Path("/rs/hello")
public class HelloWorldProgram {

    //path is default
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String sayHello() {
        return "Hello, World!";
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
    @Path("/xml")
    public String sayXMLHello() {
        return "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" + "<hello> Hello" + "</hello>";
    }
}
```

on the bundled with the JDK simple web server `com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer` ?

Comment: Have you tried if you can?

Comment: I don't know how to supply the annotated class to the Server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. Take a look at the "helloworld-pure-jax-rs" example of Jersey: https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/master/examples/helloworld-pure-jax-rs

Comment: Note: the README.MD file states "This deploys the example using Grizzly container.". But it really uses com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't use com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer. You need a server compliant with Servlet API. Instead you can use for example org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServer:

```
import java.net.URI;

import javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder;

import org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServer;
import org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpServerFactory;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;

public class Server {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        URI uri = UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost/").port(8888).build();
        ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig(HelloWorldProgram.class);
        HttpServer server = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(uri, rc);
        Thread.currentThread().join(); // keep running
    }
}
```

You will need a dependency to [Jersey Container Grizzly2 Servlet](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.containers/jersey-container-grizzly2-servlet).

Comment: How heavy is this grizzly2 thing? Size in mb as a maven dependency with all of its dependencies.

Comment: @mist jersey-container-grizzly2-servlet 2.10 and all its dependencies weight 5.6 MB, however it already includes jersey (JAX-RS framework)